# How can I heal my battle pet?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been playing around with the pokemon battle pet system added to World of Warcraft in the Mists of Pandaria expansion, and have noticed that between fights my chosen pet does not regenerate her health.

What methods are available to restore the health of my battle pet so I can continue my winning streak against the critters of Azeroth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to heal your battle pet(s), some of them heal specifically the active pet, others heal all pets. Here are the different ways you can heal:

**Winning a battle**

Winning a battle will provide a small heal and some experience to your currently active battle pet. [The amount healed is 50% of the damage that they took during the fight](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4940476355).

**Levelling a battle pet**

Gaining a level with a battle pet will restore its health to 100%.

**Visit a stable master**

For a small fee (from my testing this appears to be 10 silver and doesn't appear to increase the more times you do it) you can ask a Stable Master to revive and heal all of your battle pets.

**The battle pet interface**

You can also use the 'Revive Pets' option in the Battle Pet interface:

[image: Battle Pet Interface]

This ability has an eight minute cooldown, and fully revives and heals your battle pets.

**Battle Pet Bandages**

It is also possible to get battle pet bandages, which are bandages for your battle pets. These will heal and resurrect your battle pets to full health.

[image: Battle Pet Bandages]

Answer (score 6):

Battle Pets are account-bound, so if you leave one of your characters standing next to a a stable master, you can always log in with that character to heal your pets, and then log back in with the one you are running around battling with.

Comment: Yes, but there's a 3 minute cooldown on this that starts when you log in. So it's not usually worth it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of healing / reviving.

One is by going to a Stable Master in any city/town (it costs 10 silver).

The second is by opening up your Battle Pet / Mounts tab, and clicking on the Icon on the top right. This ability will revive and fully heal any active Battle Pets you have on your 1 - 3 slots. However, this ability can only be used once ever 8 or 9 minutes.

On a side note, all humanoid battle pets regenerate health during battle after every turn. :)

Comment: Fossilised Rapter has a heal ability which defaults to slot 2 as well

Comment: Good to know. He might have to become part of my rotation.

Comment: It may not be something specific to that pet, and could be something related to undead pets, but he's the only undead pet I have

Comment: Humanoid battle pets just regenerate 4% of the total health if they manage to do damage in that turn. This is an important distinction, because otherwise a) defensive abilities like reflect would be even more powerful on humanoids and b) humanoids would heal in the back row all the time (this would be incredibly powerful). However note that a humanoid who manages to dot up an enemy will receive the "damage dealt this turn" healing even on the back row.